# Video post in fast server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am posting video using AFNetworking 3.0 video have limit 180 seconds.Some time i am getting memory error i want to send video in chunks.short video is posted on server but when it is long i am getting memory error and app crash.

```
-(void)videoPost{
    [SVProgressHUD show];

    NSLog(@"DD Paths %@", Match_ID);
    NSString *urlString=@"http://202.164.59.107/stands_app/webservices/User/uploadfile";

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager1 = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager1.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager1 POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
         // NSLog(@"DD Paths %@", documentsDirectory);
         filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
         //NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
         NSString *fullpath;
         for ( NSString *apath in filePathsArray )
         {
             fullpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:apath];
             videoURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath];
             [URLpaths addObject:videoURL];
         }
         // NSLog(@"vurl %@",vedioURL);
         //[URLpaths removeObjectAtIndex:0];
         videoURL=[URLpaths lastObject];
         NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

         [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[self.FileType dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]name:@"type"];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[LoginID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]name:@"userid"];
         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[Match_ID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]name:@"matchid"];
     } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"Response: %@",task);
         NSLog(@"Response is success : %@", responseObject);

         NSString *Status=[responseObject valueForKey:@"success"];
         // success or not
         if([Status isEqualToString:@"1"])
         {

             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
             [Utility showAlertWithMessage:@"Video Upload sucessfully."];
         }
         else
         {
             [Utility showAlertWithMessage:@"Faul to upload video."];
         }

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
         //Error not task is sucess
         NSLog(@"Response data sucessfully : %@",task);
         [videoURL removeAllCachedResourceValues];
     }];
}
```

Comment: is the 180 seconds a limit of the server, or is 180 seconds the maximum amount of video you can upload before a memory warning brings down your app?

Comment: i add limit on camera will save automatic video when time will 180 seconds it will save in directory .

Answer (score 1):

Replace your

```
  [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
```

with

```
  [formData appendPartWithFileURL:yourFileUrlForVideo name:@"file" fileName:@"video.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime" error:nil]; //I thing videoURL is FileURL in your case
```

and comment below line,

```
  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

Because when you convert anything to `NSData` then it's use memory of your device and it's convert whole file in to data at a time. so for example if your video's size is 1000 mb and you convert it to url to data then it's require 1000 mb of memory(memory means ram!). so it's better to send data directly from disk (storage of device - i mean documentsdirectory) by using `url` without converting it's to `NSData`. So it do not use unnecessary memory.

You can take watch on your app's `memory usage` from `Debug Navigator` while your application is running.

Comment: by adding url of video how much length video i can post  on server ?

Comment: there is no limit from ios side! It's depends on your server that how much length it supports!

Comment: thanx bro but my side sucess not coming i thik my net is slow .